# Enable UDP packet checksum in C INET Socket Code

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I'm writing a UDP client to connect to a server and send some data. The server that I'm connecting to ensures that the UDP packets checksum is correct. In the documentation I'm using the following line is included: `The optional 16 bit checksum must be included in the header`.

I just wanted to know how I can ensure that this will be included. Here is my client code so far:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ip_address "127.0.0.1"
#define port_num 32000

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  int sockfd,n;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
  char sendline[1000];
  char recvline[1000];

  sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

  bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip_address);
  servaddr.sin_port=htons(port_num);

while (fgets(sendline, 10000,stdin) != NULL)
 {
     sendto(sockfd,sendline,strlen(sendline),0,
         (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
     n=recvfrom(sockfd,recvline,10000,0,NULL,NULL);
     recvline[n]=0;
     fputs(recvline,stdout);
 }
}
```

Comment: From http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/udp_user.htm, "Despite UDP checksums being optional, they should always be enabled" and "It is hard to detect whether a particular system has UDP checksums enabled. It is normally impossible for an application to obtain the checksum field in a received UDP header. To get around this, the author added another option to the tcpdump program that prints the received UDP checksum. If this printed value is 0, it means the sending host did not calculate the checksum."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudos to TCP/IP Illustrated referenced in the comment, but it is a bit aged. The packet capture tool Wireshark will happily show you the UDP checksum.

You did not mention your specific platform, but these days it is safe to assume it might be Linux. Folklore (I have no reference) says it might depend on the network interface device driver, but in my experience the UDP checksum is always added on Linux, when you send packets via regular UDP sockets.

Your code is a bit strange in the way that it tries to capture packets it sends itself. I adapted the code a bit and used netcat as the receiving server. **I verified that UDP checksums are present and correct** by running wireshark on the client side.

Here is a link to the slightly modified code http://pastebin.com/X9cgH1S3

Caveat emptor, testing on localhost with Linux will fail. My guess is that the wireshark capture socket gets the packet at the wrong point in the flow (before the checksum is calculated) or the network stack for localhost takes shortcuts. Anyway, test over the real Internet, if you can.

Comment: Thanks, I am indeed using Linux. That is great that the checksums seem to be enabled by default, but I was also wondering what code I would have to write to manually enable/disable them.

Comment: I dont think there is any way to turn it off for regular UDP sockets. You would have to create a raw/packet socket and format your own udp headers. It is not even possible to turn it off for UDPlite http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.11/Documentation/networking/udplite.txt As the kernel documentation notes, a zero checksum is forbidden on the Internet, so I dont think many implementations enable switching it off https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3828#section-3.1 . I do know there has been discussion on disabling checksums inside VPNs.